# How to plot svg circles on curved line in d3 js?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I am coding a software in which I draw some svg circles positioned side by side, which the user can adjust the position, changing the line coordinates. The desired result is this

[image]

Right now the circles are disposed with a space that is not correct, making the circles go to the left

[image]

Code

```js
function curve(val){
        var w = d3.select("#new_row_1").attr("width");

        var 
        numLines = 1,
        lineSpacing = 18,
        parabDepth = -30;

        var row_spacing = 18;

        if(val == 0){
            parabDepth = -18;
        }
        else if(val == 1){
            parabDepth = 0;
        }
        else if(val == 2){
            parabDepth = 20;
        }
        else if(val == 3){
            parabDepth = 30;
        }
        else if(val == 4){
            parabDepth = 40;
        }
        else if(val == 5){
            parabDepth = 50;
            // row_spacing = 18.41;
        }
        else if(val == 6){
            // row_spacing = 18.5;
            parabDepth = 60;
        }
        else if(val == 7){
            // row_spacing = 18.6;
            parabDepth = 70;
        }
        else if(val == 8){
            // row_spacing = 18.62;
            parabDepth = 80;
        }
        else if(val == 9){
            parabDepth = 90;
        }
        else if(val == 10){
            parabDepth = 100;
        }
        else if(val == 11){
            parabDepth = 110;
        }
        else if(val == 12){
            parabDepth = 120;
        }
        else if(val == 13){
            parabDepth = 130;
        }
        else if(val == 14){
            parabDepth = 140;
        }
        else if(val == 15){
            parabDepth = 150;
            row_spacing = 20;
        }

        width = w ;
        
        var curveData = [];

        curveData.push([0,0]);
        curveData.push([width/3 * 1, lineSpacing + parabDepth ]);
        curveData.push([width/3 * 2, lineSpacing + parabDepth ]);
        curveData.push([width/3 * 3, 1]);

        var line = d3.line()
            .x(function(d) {
              return d[0];
            })
            .y(function(d) {
              return d[1] + 8;
            })
            .curve(d3.curveCardinal);

        var svg = d3.select("#new_row_1").attr("height", (numLines * lineSpacing) + lineSpacing + parabDepth + row_spacing).attr("width", width);

        var g = svg.selectAll(".line")
            .data(d3.range(numLines))
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("transform", function(d){
              return "translate(7," + (d*lineSpacing) + ")";
            });
        
        var path = g.append("path")
            .attr("d", line(curveData))
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("stroke", "pink")
            .style("stroke-width","4")
            .each(function(){
                var g = d3.select(this.parentNode),
                    self = d3.select(this),
                    pathLength = width;
                  
                g.selectAll("circle")
                    .data(d3.range(1, width, row_spacing))
                    .enter()
                    .append("circle")
                    .attr("transform", (d,i) => {
                        var p = this.getPointAtLength(d);
                        return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
                    })
                    .attr("r", 7)
                    .style("fill", function(d,i){
                        if(i == quant_col2 - 1){
                            return "red";
                        }else if(i == quant_col2/2){
                            return "yellow";
                        }
                        else if(i == quant_col2 - 2){
                            return "green";
                        }
                        else{
                            return "white";
                        }
                    })
                    .attr("stroke","black")
                    .attr("stroke-width","1");
            });
}

setTimeout(function(){
    curve(1)
},2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg width="252" height="18" id="new_row_1" class="new_row" style="top: 150px; left: 302px; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><g><circle cx="8" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="3" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">1</text></g><g><circle cx="26" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="21" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">2</text></g><g><circle cx="44" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="39" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">3</text></g><g><circle cx="62" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="57" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">4</text></g><g><circle cx="80" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="75" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">5</text></g><g><circle cx="98" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="93" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">6</text></g><g><circle cx="116" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="111" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">7</text></g><g><circle cx="134" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="129" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">8</text></g><g><circle cx="152" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="147" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">9</text></g><g><circle cx="170" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="165" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">10</text></g><g><circle cx="188" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="183" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">11</text></g><g><circle cx="206" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="201" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">12</text></g><g><circle cx="224" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="219" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">13</text></g><g><circle cx="242" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="237" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">14</text><g class="label" style="display: none;"><rect x="126" y="1" width="14" height="14" style="fill: black;"></rect><text dx="130" dy="11" style="font-size: 9px; font-weight: 400; fill: white;">A</text></g></g></svg>
```

The value will be controlled by the user, meaning it will change dynamically. 
I want to evenly dispose them through the line. How can it be done?

Comment: Not related to your question, but you can replace that bunch of `if` statements for a scale... It's simpler and easier to change.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I know it is a math related question, this if was just a way to simulate the curves. I need to change it, but I believe once I dispose the circles evenly, this part of the code will not be necessary. Thanks, you're right about it.

Comment: Actually, I just saw that a scale won't do it (you don't have a linear correspondence), but you can reduce it to just a couple of `if... else`, check the code in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `getPointAtLength()` to find the X,Y coordinates of a point at a distance along the curve.  Obvoiously that's wrong. You want to find the Y coord for a given X.

There is no built-in SVG function for that.  You are going to have to calculate that yourself.  For that you would need the polynomial form of the bezier equation, which is not trivial.

Since you are only making a parabola, you would be better to avoid using bezier curves at all, and just calculate your curve using the normal simple quadratic equation (*ax^2 + bx + c*).

*Aside: if you do decide to stick with bezier curves, then you should really use a quadratic bezier, instead of a cbic one. Quadratic beziers have the property that they always form a segmnt of a parabola.*

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `width`, you should use `getTotalLength()` for the size of the line:

```
pathLength = this.getTotalLength();
```

Here is the demo with that change only:

```js
function curve(val) {
  var w = d3.select("#new_row_1").attr("width");

  var
    numLines = 1,
    lineSpacing = 18,
    parabDepth = -30;

  var row_spacing = 18;

  if (val == 0) {
    parabDepth = -18;
  } else if (val == 1) {
    parabDepth = 0;
  } else if (val == 15) {
    parabDepth = 150;
    row_spacing = 20;
  } else {
    parabDepth = val * 10;
  }

  width = w;

  var curveData = [];

  curveData.push([0, 0]);
  curveData.push([width / 3 * 1, lineSpacing + parabDepth]);
  curveData.push([width / 3 * 2, lineSpacing + parabDepth]);
  curveData.push([width / 3 * 3 - 8, - 8]);

  var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return d[0];
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d[1];
    })
    .curve(d3.curveCardinal);

  var svg = d3.select("#new_row_1").attr("height", (numLines * lineSpacing) + lineSpacing + parabDepth + row_spacing).attr("width", width);

  var g = svg.selectAll(".line")
    .data(d3.range(numLines))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(7," + (d * lineSpacing + 7) + ")";
    });

  var path = g.append("path")
    .attr("d", line(curveData))
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "pink")
    .style("stroke-width", "4")
    .each(function() {
      var g = d3.select(this.parentNode),
        self = d3.select(this),
        pathLength = this.getTotalLength();

      g.selectAll("circle")
        .data(d3.range(1, pathLength, row_spacing))
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("transform", (d, i) => {
          var p = this.getPointAtLength(d);
          return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
        })
        .attr("r", 7)
        .style("fill", "darkslategray")
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", "1");
    });
}

setTimeout(function() {
  curve(5)
}, 500)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg width="252" height="18" id="new_row_1" class="new_row" style="top: 150px; left: 302px; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><g><circle cx="8" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="3" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">1</text></g><g><circle cx="26" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="21" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">2</text></g><g><circle cx="44" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="39" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">3</text></g><g><circle cx="62" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="57" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">4</text></g><g><circle cx="80" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="75" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">5</text></g><g><circle cx="98" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="93" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">6</text></g><g><circle cx="116" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="111" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">7</text></g><g><circle cx="134" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="129" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">8</text></g><g><circle cx="152" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="147" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">9</text></g><g><circle cx="170" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="165" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">10</text></g><g><circle cx="188" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="183" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">11</text></g><g><circle cx="206" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="201" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">12</text></g><g><circle cx="224" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="219" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">13</text></g><g><circle cx="242" cy="8" r="7" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"></circle><text dx="237" dy="11" class="label" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; display: none;">14</text><g class="label" style="display: none;"><rect x="126" y="1" width="14" height="14" style="fill: black;"></rect><text dx="130" dy="11" style="font-size: 9px; font-weight: 400; fill: white;">A</text></g></g></svg>
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `width`, you shouldn't use `getPointAtLength()`, as LeBeau explains in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43288986/5768908), because in Euclidean geometry a straight line is shorter than any other geometric shape going from point A to point B.

Besides that, you have two problems: 1. there are a lot of magic numbers everywhere, and 2. you could design a better math to get the arc. I believe you should get rid of this code and write an entirely new, different approach.

Comment: Hi, @gerardo-furtado, this approach won't work for my purpose, since it creates more circles along the line. Instead, it should spread them along the  curved line...

Comment: In that case, as LeBeau said, just calculate the y point for a given x point.